# Text and Link will not align correctly on the same line

Tags: html, css

I want to have the following text and link be on the same line, with the text 'Made by XYZ' centered and the return to top link on the right. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="footer_container">
    <span style="text-align: center">Made by XYZ</span>
    <span style="float: right"><a href="#top">Return to Top</a></span>
</div>
```

Here is the div containers code:

```
#footer_container
{
    background: #7fc041;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1.9em;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can only apply [`text-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop) on block-level elements, so use it on `#footer_container` instead.

Comment: You don't need to wrap your link with a span to float it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the `text-align:center` to your footer instead of the span ([only block level elements support this property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop)). Additionally, you don't need a span to float your anchor tag:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer_container">
    <span>Made by XYZ</span>
    <a href="#top" style="float: right">Return to Top</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer_container
{
    background: #7fc041;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1.9em;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2h7V/).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However when I apply margin-right to the return to top link it moves over the made by xyz text also. How do I prevent that?

Comment: @DavidTunnell, this is expected (normal) behavior. To accomodate, simply add a matching negative margin to the `xyz` text. http://jsfiddle.net/Ge465/

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
#footer_container
{
    background: #7fc041;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1.9em;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center
}

<div id="footer_container">
    <span>Made by XYZ</span>
    <span style="float: right"><a href="#top">Return to Top</a></span>
</div>
```

Check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtEhK/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However when I apply margin-right to the return to top link it moves over the made by xyz text also. How do I prevent that?

Comment: A little hacky, but look on [these lines](http://jsfiddle.net/KtEhK/2/). Easier way (which is a hack too) is to add a negative margin to the first span.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/8NLeN/
Add this in css:

```
#footer_container
{
   text-align:center
}
```